# argparse: unable to get subparser_name after declaring a global argument

Tags: python, parsing, argparse

I've got a parser with some sub-parsers. I setup a global argument to be used on all subparser. Here's the relevant snippet

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="my_prog", add_help=False)
parser.add_argument('-d', '--debug', action='store_true', help='debug flag')

subparsers =  parser.add_subparsers(dest="subparser_name", help='some help notes')

parser_cmd1 = subparsers.add_parser('cmd1', parents=[parser])
parser_cmd1.add_argument('-f', '-foo', type=str, action=foo, required=False, help='foo command')

parser_cmd2 = subparsers.add_parser('cmd2', parents=[parser])
parser_cmd2.add_argument('-b', '-bar', type=str, action=bar, required=False, help='bar command')

args = parser.parse_args()
parser = args.subparser_name

print(args)

if args.debug:
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

if parser == 'cmd1':
    if args.foo:
        //do foo stuff

if parser == 'cmd2':
    if args.bar:
        //do bar stuff
```

So you can a command like such `my_prog.py cmd1 -d -f inp_str`. Here's the problem: subparser_name is None. The output of print(args) looks kind of like this

```
Namespace(debug=True, foo="inp_str", subparser_name=None)
```

Before I added the global debug argument, subparser_name would be the name of the command I ran, i.e. 'cmd1' or 'cmd2'. Now, it's 'None'. Even with the parents=[parser] addition in the subparser creation. How can I fix this? How do I know which command was called?

Comment: What version of Python? What OS? And please make your code in your question a [mre] so I can try it simply by copy/paste and running the file _without having to add anything_

Comment: Don't use the main parser as parent to the subpaarsers.  And don't try to use arguments with thd same `dest` in both the main and sub.

Comment: Not that it's relevant to the problem, but specifying `action` as `foo` or `bar` does make this unreproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split out the common args to a separate ArgumentParser, which is then used as parent for the sub parsers. Also your foo and bar options were specified using -foo and -bar whi should be --foo and --bar. Also you didn't have default values for these so e.g. when -f/--foo wasn't specified args.foo correctly didn't exist.

This works better:

```
import argparse

common_args = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="my_prog", add_help=False)
common_args.add_argument('-d', '--debug', action='store_true', help='debug flag')

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="my_prog", add_help=True)

subparsers =  parser.add_subparsers(dest="subparser_name", help='some help notes')

parser_cmd1 = subparsers.add_parser('cmd1', parents=[common_args])
parser_cmd1.add_argument('-f', '--foo', type=str, default='', required=False, help='foo command')

parser_cmd2 = subparsers.add_parser('cmd2', parents=[common_args])
parser_cmd2.add_argument('-b', '--bar', type=str, default='', required=False, help='bar command')

args = parser.parse_args()
parser = args.subparser_name

print(args)

if args.debug:
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

if parser == 'cmd1':
    if args.foo:
        #//do foo stuff
        print( f"foo {args.foo}" )

if parser == 'cmd2':
    if args.bar:
        #//do bar stuff
        print( f"bar {args.bar}" )
```

run with:

```
args.py cmd1 -f asd
```

output:

```
Namespace(subparser_name='cmd1', debug=False, foo='asd')
foo asd
```

Update:

If you want to be able to use e.g. `args.py -d cmd1` then on the creation of `parser`, specify `parents=[common_args]`

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="my_prog", add_help=True, parents=[common_args])
```

Next time you ask a question ensure you only post code as a minimal reproducible example - i.e. that can be run *without adding anything*

Comment: updated with how to use -d without having to specify sub command.

Answer (score 0):

The subparser's defaults have priority of any values set by the main parser - default or user input.  The main does `set the subparser_name` to 'cmd1', but the subparser changes it back to the default `None`.

While not evident in your test case, defining `debug` at both levels has the same problem.  The subparser's default overwrites anything set in the main.

In general, it is not a good idea to use the same `dest` in the main and subparsers.  Flags can be the same, but the `dest` should be different - at least if you want to see anything set by the main.

And using the main parser as a `parent` to the sub, is just asking for confusion.